# Error converting List<KeyValuePair<,>> to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, ienumerable, covariance

Why I'm able to do this:

```
IEnumerable<object> objs;
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
objs = students;
```

But not this:

```
IEnumerable<object> objs2;
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> kvs = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "ab"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "xy")
};
objs2 = kvs; //error
```

the error thrown:

> ```
> >     Cannot implicitly convert type
> > 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,
> > string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'. An
> > explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> ```

the accepted answer in the duplicated question is that the `KeyValuePair` is a struct, though this conversion passes without any error:

```
KeyValuePair<int, string> kv = new KeyValuePair<int, string>();
object oj = kv;
```

so I'm assuming that there is something to do with covariance and contravariance that is missing!

Comment: You just declare two objects in the first sample. Did you miss something there?

Comment: and what _is_ the error?

Comment: That there is a conversion error between `List<Object>` and `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>`

Comment: That is more detailed than the question.

Comment: try this: objs2 = kvs.Select(x => (object)x);

Comment: @daniell89 The solution is simple, but whats interesting about this is the cause

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Sorry, I amended the code

Comment: _"this conversion passes without any error"_ -- what conversion? The first statement there isn't even legal. You can't assign `KeyValuePair<int, bool>` to `KeyValuePair<int, string>`. And the conversion from `kv` to `oj` is completely different from the conversion you're trying to make in your question.